# Special decoration for TikZ pin feature

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, decorations, node-connections, pgf-decorations

I try to achieve the curvy pin style I sketched below. It would help to distinguish pin lines from grid and other lines in the diagram.

[image: Curvy pins]

1. How can I realize a decoration that automatically draws such a curve?
2. How can I integrate this with the pin feature?

The code for the picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    pin distance=5mm,
    every pin edge/.style={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            snake,
            pre length=4pt
        }
    }
]
  \begin{axis}[
    width=12cm,
    height=5cm,
    xmin=0,xmax=4,
    ]

    \addplot coordinates {(1,1) (3,3)}
    coordinate [pos=.5] (a) coordinate [pos=.7] (b);

    \node [pin=135:From the manual] at (a) {};

    \path (a) ++(-45:1cm) node (c) {What I want};
    \draw [gray] (c) to[out=110,in=-70] (a);

    \path (b) ++(-45:.8cm) node [right] (d) {What I want II};
    \draw [gray] (d.west) to[out=160,in=-20] (b);

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(I tagged with pgfplots as well since this would be a common application.)

Comment: You can use `every pin edge/.style={
        out=-70,in=70
        }` or whatever!. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @HarishKumar: This would set a fix angle, but what I need is a solution that takes the angle of the line into account, so that I can define arbitrary pin angles but maintain the overall look (I know that the pin angle and the pin line's angle are not necessarily equal, what makes it even more difficult for me to find a solution, otherwise I could maybe somehow access the angle in the code and calculate the in and out angles).

Comment: I'm not clear how you want it to work, quite, given that the angles of the line look to vary independently of other things, and that the placement of the label with respect to the end of the pin varies independently of other things. That is, it looks like the kind of thing where you are varying stuff deliberately in ways which could not be calculated. Is there a pattern I'm missing?

Comment: @cfr: Maybe my sketch is a bit misleading. I want the pin edges to always look the same, independent of the drawn angle or the given angle, and I want one style for bend left–bend right and one for bend right–bend left. I guess the TikZ internals know about the angle and start and end coordinates of the drawn edge, which would allow, if one could access them, to define the parameters in and out in the right way, or maybe spline control points or whatever. Something like out=drawn_angle+30°, in=drawn_angle-30°. Is this more clear?

Comment: You can use `relative` style. In this way `in` and `out` angles are relative to the the edge direction. But be careful with pins in some situations they behave in a strange way. For example in your case `every pin edge/.style={relative, out=25,in=190}` looks ok, but `every pin edge/.style={relative, out=35,in=215}` looks not so good :( In the `relative` mode the stright line is `{relative, out=0,in=180}`.